# htaccess on Localhost refers to root, not folder

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am working on a website to make the URL's more SEO friendly with the `htaccess`, however, i bump into a problem when I set up the htaccess file. If I use the URLs I prefer to setup, i get refered back to the localhost and not towards the development map I am working in, so in this case, i get refered back to `localhost/blog` for example instead of `localhost/jellyfish_rework/blog`, so I end up with a view from my `localhost`or simply an error in the page.

The original link was `http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/index.php?p=blog`

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /jellyfish_rework/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /?p=$1 [L]]
```

Does this have to do with the fact my `anchors` refer to `<a href"/blog"></a>`? Cause in the other `anchor` tags that I still refer to in the old way, I dont get the responds back I want (so the link stays `http://localhost/jellyfish_rework/index.php?p=blog`)

edit

the `htaccess` file is located in the localhost/jellyfish_rework/ as that is where the index file is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your last line (`RewriteRule`) should look like this

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [L]
```

**Don't** add a leading slash before.
Otherwise it will be like an **absolute** path (`/index.php` from root).

With the rule above and your `RewriteBase`, this rule will act this way:
`If not existing file/folder then rewrite it to /jellyfish_rework/index.php?p=URI`

Your old rule (with leading slash) was about:
`If not existing file/folder then rewrite it to /index.php?p=URI`

**Note**: since you're using relative paths, you must also change all your html links (css, javascript, images, links) with a leading `/jellyfish_rework/` or use the `base` tag

```
<base href="/jellyfish_rework/">
```

Comment: `[Tue Sep 30 14:35:34.010351 2014] [core:alert] [pid 5556:tid 936] [client ::1:50767] E:/Documenten/Websites/wamp/www/JellyFish_Rework/.htaccess: RewriteRule: bad flag delimiters` hmmm iget now a bad flag delimiter.

Comment: Yes, i fixed it, made a typo when i took over the rewriterule to understand it, and i hit when i pressed control s to save it not the control button well, so it planted an s behind it before i saved it again ;) And it works like a charm now ;) thank you